# Dialogflow PHP rest api

Tags: php

PHP REST Api used for Dialog Flow detectIntent() function gives internal server error.

We are connecting to Google Dialog flow service from AWS EC2 instance. But we are receiving internal server error 500.

Comment: Is this the part where we should start guessing what your code looks like and what your servers error log says? This is like asking a car mechanic to tell you what's wrong with your car without letting them look at it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried many solution, I initially thought it was AWS EC2 Instance problem because Dialog flow code is working fine to my local windows server but not on AWS server.

After few research, i found that it was the problem of bcMath module which is not installed on my EC2 Instance php setting.

Following are the steps to install bcMath module on PHP - 
 1. First check if you have bcMath. Check this using phpinfo(); function.
 2. Use following command to install bcMath on your AWS instance php - 
$sudo yum install php55-bcmath